# Change max UDP Packet Size

Tags: windows, udp, packet, packet-capture, packet-loss

It seems that I'm not able to receive UDP Packets with a message bigger than 4096 bytes.
Where can I change this limit?

Is it OS or network adapter related?

I got this issue on my Windows Server 2012 R2 while it's working fine on my Windows 8.1 pc.

Any hint would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to raise the socket send buffer size at the sender, and the socket receive buffer size at the receiver. However the generally accepted practical limit on UDP payload size is 534 bytes. Above that, they can be fragmented, and if a fragment doesn't arrive the entire datagram is lost.

Comment: I'm using the open source software Packetsender (http://packetsender.com/) for testing purposes (so the software limits you stated shouldn't be the problem in this case).
When I'm using it on my local Win 8.1 pc I'll get the expected response (over 4096 bytes) each time I try it.
When I do the same on my Win Server 2012 I will only get a response if the packet size is smaller 4096 bytes (even when I try it 100 times so I think it can't be packetloss). So i guess it has to be OS or network adapter related as I'm using the same software to receive and send the packets.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the Microsoft documentation for socket options](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740532(v=vs.85).aspx), there's a `SO_MAX_MSG_SIZE` option that is "the maximum outbound message size for message-oriented sockets supported by the protocol."  UDP sockets are "message-oriented sockets" (as opposed to "stream-oriented sockets"; TCP sockets are stream-oriented).

This suggests that there is a maximum message size imposed by the operating system.  Sadly, that page does *not* say "yes" in the "Set" column for the `SO_MAX_MSG_SIZE` row, so your program can't override that maximum.